# write_html() method in fpdf not using font/encoding specified

Tags: html, python-3.6, fpdf

I'm creating a PDF with a large collection of quotes that I've imported into python with docx2python, using html=True so that they have some tags. I've done some processing to them so they only really have the bold, italics, underline, or break tags. I've sorted them and am trying to write them onto a PDF using the [fpdf library](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), specifically the `pdf.write_html(quote)` method. The trouble comes with several special characters I have, so I am hoping to encode the PDF to UTF-8. To write with `.write_html()`, I had to create a new class as shown in their readthedocs under the `.write_html()` method at the very bottom of the left hand side:

```
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
class htmlFPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
     pass
pdf = htmlFPDF()
pdf.add_page()
#set the overall PDF to utf-8 to preserve special characters
pdf.set_doc_option('core_fonts_encoding', 'utf-8')
pdf.write_html(quote) #[![a section of quote giving trouble with quotations][2]][2]
```

The list of quotes that I have going into the pdf all appear with their special characters and the html tags (`<u>` or `<i>`) in the debugger, but after the `.write_html()` step they then show up in the pdf file with mojibake, even before being saved, as seen through debugger. An example being "dayÃ¢Â€ÂTMs demands", when it should be "day's demands" (the apostrophe is curled clockwise in the quote, but this textbox doesn't support).

I've tried updating the font I use by

```
pdf.add_font('NotoSans', '', 'NotoSans-Regular.ttf', uni=True)
pdf.set_font('NotoSans', '', size=12)
```

added after the `.add_page()` method, but this doesn't change the current font (or fix mojibake) on the PDF unless I use the more common `.write(text_height, quote)` method, which renders the underline/italicize tags into the PDF as text. The `.write()` method **does** preserve the special characters. I'm not trying to change the font really, but make sure that what's written onto the PDF preserves the special characters instead of mojibake them.
I've also attempted some .encode/.decode action before going into the `.write_html()`, as well as attempted some methods from the ftfy library. And tried adding '' to the start of each quote to no effect.

If anyone has ideas for a way to iterate through each line on the PDF that'd be terrific, since then I could use ftfy to fix the mojibake. But ideally, it would be some other html tag at the start of each quote or a way to change the font/encoding of the `.write_html()` method, maybe in the class declaration?
Or if I'm at a dead-end and should just split each quote on '<', use if statements to detect underlines, italicize, etc., and use the `.write()` method after all.

Answer (score 0):

Extract docx to html works really bad with docx2python. I do this few month ago. I recommend PyDocX. docx2python are good for docx file content extracting, not converting it into a html.